# Incorrect syntax near '=' Error: dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my search button on MasterPage.master

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Search" style="width:339px ; height: 20px;" runat="server" placeholder="Search Woooo" class="textbox" formnovalidate="formnovalidate"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonSearch" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/search.png" Width="22px" OnClick="ImageButtonSearch_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
```

MasterPage.master.cs

```
protected void ImageButtonSearch_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/search.aspx?Search=" + Search.Value);
}
```

search.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string cs = Global.CS;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string search = Request.QueryString["search"];

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string xx = "";
            string sql = @"SELECT studentID FROM Student WHERE username == '"+ search + "'";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                xx += string.Format("{0}",dr["sudentID"]);
            }

            dr.Close();
            con.Close();

            test.InnerHtml = xx;
        }
    }
}
```

I wanna try search based on username on the search box. But after i clicked on search button, it display Incorrect syntax near '='. Source error: dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();. I already search the problem through many places but i still can't understand. I'm still new at c#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing SQL with C#. Equality comparison is done with a single `=`.

More importantly, you are vulnerable to SQL injection. You should take care of this first.

The SQL should look like this:

```sql
SELECT studentID FROM Student WHERE username = @username
```

And you should add the parameter `@username` to your C# code, like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@username").Value = search;
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that in T-SQL a SINGLE equal sign is required:
`@"SELECT studentID FROM Student WHERE username = '"+ search + "'";`

(next to username `=` )

**UPD** As Patrick Hofman points out above, you might want to research SQL injection and common ways to protect against it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Comment: I don't hope they enter `'; drop table students --` as user name.

Comment: @PatrickHofman sure, you noticed it, i only pointed out the reason for the exception. Thanks for downvoting :)